What is the expected behavior of DNS across two servers in windows domain
Have 2 domain controllers, DC01 and DC02 with DNS and DHCP roles. Replicaton, DNS and DHCP failover were all working great. Migrated from 2012r2 to 2022 datacenter a
couple months ago. We hired the migration out to a 3rd party. DHCP scopes specify DC01 as primary DNS and DC02 as secondary. Workstationas are all Windows 10. DC01 went
down yesterday. DC02 was up but most users couldn't login and DNS appeared to be wonky for local workstations. I say wonky because I never got to the bottom of it before
DC01 was brought back up but most workstations seemed to be stuck trying DC01 for DNS and not attempting DC02 at all. Querying directly to DC02 worked fine for DNS except
querying directly to DC02, no SRV records could be queried for awhile. I say awhile because eventually it started working again although DC01 was still down.
The SRV records were indeed showing in DNS manager on DC02 at the time.
One issue is that for a couple appliances we specify domain.local for the LDAP address and was working fine for a bit after DC01 went down then stopped. Querying DNS for
domain.local did resolve the two DCs Ip addresses. So I tried pinging domain.local from a workstation but this was intermittent depnding on what DNS servers were specified
in TCP/IP properties on the workstations. I assumed by just using DC02 for DNS this should resolve the issues for the moment but it did not. Another issue is on the
Windows workstations after DC01 went down. They were only recording DC01 for primary DNS server, no secondary despite both DCs being listed in the scopes. A reboot of the
workstations rectified this and both DCs were then recorded for DNS primary and secondary respectively. What confuses me is why the workstations were not recording both
DCs for DNS after DC01 went down(they were previously), and why reaching domain.local became so intermittent. The only place we're specifying domain.local is the
appliances which only allow one LDAP server per domain. It's a limitation of the firmware.
Pinging domain.local I've tried the following keeping in mind I hadn't cleared DNS cache yet:
Set pc to DNS of DC02 only, ping domain.local fails but resolves to DC01
Set pc to DNS of .DC01 and DC02, ping domain.local works
Set pc to DNS of random IP and DC01, ping domain.local fails with ping request could not find host domain.local
-why is not using previously cached DNS?
Now no matter what combination of DNS servers, still fails at this point.
Set pc to DNS of DC01 only and it fails but resolves to DC01
Set pc to DNS of random IP only and it says ping request could not find host domain.local
-why is not using cache still
Set pc to DNS of DC01 and DC02 AGAIN and it fails but resolves to DC01
-using cache again likely?
Flushing DNS did not correct this. At the end of day setting the pc back to DC01 as primary and DC02 seondary for DNS started working again on it's own eventually. No
changes on my part. Is there something about DNS in and AD environment that I'm missing? Anyone else seen this behavior?

You need to check AD replication.  Use repadmin /showreps on both DC`s.

All are successful.
